# Node.js Sequelize Postgres related search function

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a search function which can also show related searches. For example. If I try to search 'trees' then it must find me all the rows which contains trees. and which I mistype it then too it must show me some results. For example. 'treesabc' then too it must show me some results. For now I am using Like method which satisfies my first need but it does works when entered addition letters.

So here is my code.

```
exports.quickSearch = async (req, res) => {
  let services = [];
  // finding all services which matches the condition
  let serviceData = await Service.findAll({
    limit: 300, //  limiting the number of search

    where: {
      // here i want to to do something which can also show related searches
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          service_name: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn("LOWER", sequelize.col("service_name")),
            "LIKE",
            "%" + req.params.keyword.toLowerCase() + "%",
          ),
        },
        {
          category: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn("LOWER", sequelize.col("category")),
            "LIKE",
            "%" + req.params.keyword.toLowerCase() + "%",
          ),
        },
        {
          sub_category: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn("LOWER", sequelize.col("sub_category")),
            "LIKE",
            "%" + req.params.keyword.toLowerCase() + "%",
          ),
        },
        {
          master_category: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn("LOWER", sequelize.col("master_category")),
            "LIKE",
            "%" + req.params.keyword.toLowerCase() + "%",
          ),
        },
        {
          gender: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn("LOWER", sequelize.col("gender")),
            "LIKE",
            "%" + req.params.keyword.toLowerCase() + "%",
          ),
        },
      ],
    },
  });
  // custom function asyncForEach
  const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      await callback(array[i]);
    }
  };
  await asyncForEach(serviceData, async (service) => {
//  trying to find all te partner which has service_id
    let partnerData = await Partner.findOne({
      where: {
        partner_id: service.partner_id,
        banned: false,
      },
      raw: true,
    });

    if (partnerData) {
      // inserting partners data in service
      partnerData.password = null;
      service.dataValues.outletdata = partnerData;
      services.push(service);
    }
  });
  
  return res
    .status(200)
    .json({ message: "Success", services});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Op.like`:

Example:

```
queryParams.where = {
 [Op.or]: [
  Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('t_device.name')), {
   [Op.like]: `%${optionsWithDefault.search}%`,
  }),
  Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('t_device.external_id')), {
   [Op.like]: `%${optionsWithDefault.search}%`,
  }),
```

Reference Link : https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/sequelize/SequelizeStatic/fn